# use post-order binary tree traverse to calculate number of subtrees

Tags: python, recursion

I'm practicing some Leetcode tree/recursion problems. I still haven't gotten a hang of them. The problem is given the root of a binary tree, return the number of subtrees, in which all the nodes having the same value.  https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/data-structure-tree/17/solve-problems-recursively/538/.My solution returns fewer subtrees than the correct answer. I couldn't figure it out. thank you.

```
class Solution:
    def countUnivalSubtrees(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if root is None:
            return 0
        
        self.count = 0
        self.isUnivalSubtree(root)
        return self.count
    
    def isUnivalSubtree(self, root:TreeNode) -> bool:
        
        if (root.left is None) and (root.right is None):
            self.count += 1
            return True

        if (root.left is None) and (root.right is not None):
            if self.isUnivalSubtree(root.right) and (root.val == root.right.val):
                self.count += 1
                return True
            else:
                return False
            
        if (root.right is None) and (root.left is not None):
            if self.isUnivalSubtree(root.left) and (root.val == root.left.val):
                self.count += 1
                return True
            else:
                return False
            
        if (root.right is not None) and (root.left is not None):
            if self.isUnivalSubtree(root.left) and self.isUnivalSubtree(root.right) and (root.val == root.left.val) and (root.val == root.right.val):
                self.count += 1
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Comment: The problem is blocked by a paywall. It would be nice if you could share some inputs and the expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**recursion**

We can use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to solve the problem in a pain-free way -

1. if the input tree, `t`, is empty there is nothing to count. return the empty count, `0`
2. (inductive) `t` is not empty. if `t` is a unival, return `1` plus the result of the recursive sub-problems, `t.left` and `t.right`
3. (inductive) `t` is not empty nor is it a unival. return the sum of the result of the recursive sub-problems, `t.left` and `t.right`

```py
def count_univals(t):
  if not t:
    return 0                                                   #1
  elif is_unival(t):
    return 1 + count_univals(t.left) + count_univals(t.right)  #2
  else:
    return count_univals(t.left) + count_univals(t.right)      #3
```

This depends on defining `is_unival` which we can do using similar reasoning -

1. if the input tree, `t`, is empty, there is nothing to compare. Return true
2. (inductive) `t` is not empty. Return true if `t.val` matches the comparison value, `q`, and the recursive sub-problems `(t.left, q)` and `(t.right, q)` are also univals. Otherwise return false.

```py
def is_unival(t, q):
  if not t:
    return True                                                          #1
  else:
    return t.val == q and is_unival(t.left, q) and is_unival(t.right, q) #2
```

**iteration**

Maybe it's more intuitive for you to write it with a generic traversal method, such as `preorder` -

```py
def count_unival_subtrees(t):
  return sum(1 if is_unival(node) else 0 for node in preorder(t))

def is_unival(t):
  for node in preorder(t):
    if node.val != t.val:
      return False
  return True

def preorder(t):
  if not t: return
  yield t
  yield from preorder(t.left)
  yield from preorder(t.right)
```

**demonstration**

Either implementation you choose, they work the same way -

```py
t1 = node(1, node(1, node(2), node(1)), node(1, None, node(2)))
#     1
#    / \
#   1   1
#  / \   \
# 2   1   2

print(count_univals(t1))
```

```py
3
```

And here's a slightly more complex tree -

```py
t2 = node \
  ( 1
  , node(2, node(2, node(2), node(2)), node(5))
  , node(3, None, node(3, node(3), node(3)))
  )
#       1
#      / \
#     2   3
#    / \   \
#   2   5   3
#  / \     / \
# 2   2   3   3 
print(count_univals(t2))
```

```py
8
```

Comment: That's a very nice answer. Thank you! Appreciate it!